# handling a month and day of the week variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, mode, timeserieschart

I am trying to do some data analysis on a dataset which among other things has a column for month (recorded as `"jan",..., "dec"`) and day of the week (`"mon",...,"fri"`). I have two questions.  My first question is how can I get the mode of these variables using the `mfv` function in the `modeest` package. I have a feeling this has something to do with type of variable I need to make it (factor, character etc.). I would rather not recode the data into a numeric variable.

If I make the variables factors I can get a plot by going `plot(data$month)`, but now my plot is in alphabetical order and not temporal order, how can I change this?

Thanks!

Comment: To the person who silently downvoted: This is the [summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), so I suggest you do one of a few things 1) Explain why the downvote, 2) Explain to the OP how to improve the question 3) Edit the question so it is a good question.

Answer (score 2):

> If I make the variables factors I can get a plot by going
>   plot(data$month), but now my plot is in alphabetical order and not
>   temporal order, how can I change this?

In regards to that one, the trick is to make a new factor which is the same as the old one, but with the levels in a different order:

```
data$month <- factor(data$month, levels=tolower(month.abb))
```

Regarding the use of `mfv`. `?mfv` clearly states

> This function returns the most frequent value(s) in a given *numerical* vector

However coerce a factor to numeric within the function call

```
mfv(as.numeric(data$month))
```